# How to connect to a Wi-Fi network and access the internet on all Android versions?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app that requires the user to connect to a Wi-Fi network and access the internet. I am currently using the following code to connect to a Wi-Fi network on Android devices with version Q and above:

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private void connectToWifi(String ssid, String password) {
        WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .build();

        NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                .build();


        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Wi-Fi: " + ssid);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
                super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
                if (networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected to internet via Wi-Fi: " + ssid);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                super.onUnavailable();
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to Wi-Fi: " + ssid);
            }
        };
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    }
```

However, this code does not work on older Android versions. How can I modify this code to connect to a Wi-Fi network and access the internet on all Android versions? Are there any backward-compatible solutions?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!